# Анимация отображается поверх navigationbar-а на 5м андроиде

Tags: android, анимация, xamarin

Диалог должен выплывать снизу и уезжать обратно, но на 5м андроиде он выплывает поверх navigation bar-а. Как сделать так чтобы он был под ним?
[image: скриншот]

Показываю кастомный диалог:

```
        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TopActivity, Resource.Style.alertDialog);
        var view = TopActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.alert_dialog, null);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.message).Text = message;
        view.SetBackgroundColor(_colorByTypeMap[type]);
        view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.icon).SetBackgroundResource(_iconByTypeMap[type]);

        builder.SetCancelable(true);
        var dialog = builder.Create();
        dialog.Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchModal, WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchModal);
        dialog.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DimBehind);
        dialog.Show();
        dialog.SetContentView(view);
```

Styles.xml:

```
<style name="alertDialog" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/AlertDialogAnimation</item>
</style>
<style name="AlertDialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/popup_alert_show</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/popup_alert_hide</item>
</style>
```

анимация popup_alert_show:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fromYDelta="200%"
     android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
     android:duration="@integer/alertDialogAnimationDurationMillis"/>
</set>
```

popup_alert_hide:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fromYDelta="0%"
     android:toYDelta="200%"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
     android:duration="@integer/alertDialogAnimationDurationMillis"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Был такой, вопрос, но ответа так и не нашли - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624406

Answer (score 0):

Just use  `<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>` for activity where you show your dialog. In this case your dialog will be under navigation bar during animation.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на [ru.so]. На данном сайте принято задавать вопросы и давать ответы на **русском** языке.